# Pandas: Remove aggfun np.sum labels and value labels from pivot table

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas

I have created a pandas pivot table, and I am trying to remove the 'sum' and 'LENGTH' rows from the output xlsx.

So far I have tried to remove the two rows upon exporting the pivot table to xlsx.
I have tried to read in the exported pivot table and DataFrame.drop the two rows and re-export.

I am not having much luck. Thanks all in advance!

Link to pic:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmjFy.png

Comment: Better is use text as image, because text in image cannot be easy copied.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel([0,1])
print df
STATUS     X    Y    Z
CODE                  
A       13.0    6   20
B        NaN  472  472
C        NaN  105  105
D       13.0  584  598
```

And then maybe [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print df
  CODE     X    Y    Z
0    A  13.0    6   20
1    B   NaN  472  472
2    C   NaN  105  105
3    D  13.0  584  598
```

Comment: My goal was to find sum of column Z (among other values) and I thought if I simplified the df this would be easier accomplished.I ended up using loc['All',(u'sum', u'LENGTH', u'Z')] to store the value as a variable. I will try your suggestion too and see the results. This is my first post and I would like to give credit for the help. Thanks everyone.